# Extracting data of pairs without the data that encountered before

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a data which inside of some pairs. But some pairs go a pair that encountered before. I don't want to extract same data again. For example I have a data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P4xy.png).

So, as you see p3's first item goes p1. However p0's first item has gone that element before.

First, I have defined all pairs first like this

```
(define p2 (cons 2 3))
(define p4 (cons 4 5))
(define p1 (cons p2 1))
(define p3 (cons p1 p4))
(define p0 (cons p1 p3))
```

then I extracted all pairs by using recursion

```
(define (extract pair)
  (if (pair? pair) (append (extract (car pair)) (extract (cdr pair))) (list pair)))
```

And I get the result of

```
(2 3 1 2 3 1 4 5)
```

However, I don't want to extract `(2 3 1)` again because I have encountered before. How can I detect that?

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/memo/index.html

Comment: I have tried to import it by using `(require memo)` however i get an error which is collection not found

Comment: You'd have to install it with `raco pkg install memo` from a command line, or though the DrRacket package manager if you prefer a GUI.

Comment: (not sure how it'd be helpful here though)

Comment: I tried to manipulate output and I get correct answer, however the code still writes the element that have encountered before, after that it deletes from output :(

Comment: You should include what the desired result is in your question.

Comment: I want `(2 3 1 4 5)` instead of `(2 3 1 2 3 1 4 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `(union x y)` instead of `(append x y)`:

```lisp
(define (extract pair)
   (if (pair? pair)
       (union (extract (car pair)) (extract (cdr pair)))
       (list pair)))
       
(define (union A B)
   (cond [(empty? A) B]
         [else 
            (let ([C (union (rest A) B)])
                 (cond [(member (first A) C) C]
                       [else (cons (first A) C)]))]))
                       
(define p2 (cons 2 3))
(define p4 (cons 4 5))
(define p1 (cons p2 1))
(define p3 (cons p1 p4))
(define p0 (cons p1 p3)) 

(extract p0)
```